# Monotouch NavigationController Transition Style

Tags: c#, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, navigationcontroller

I am using Monotouch storyboard for Iphone. I have a navigation controller and through code I am setting the navigationbarhidden to false or true on certain views. I am setting the visibility in ViewWIllAppear method and it is working.

Now I am trying the following code but it has no effect on the navigation bar. I want the navigation bar to fade in or do a transition effect. But it is not working..

`this.NavigationController.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve`.

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ModalTransitionStyle` is using for other purpose.

Imaging you have 2 `UIViewController`, one of them is visible right now. You want to show modally second one with animation. Using `ModalTransitionStyle` property you could select one of predefined animation. For demo of these animations see [that video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9sUcV0nOSw).

`UINavigationController` have `ModalTransitionStyle` too cause it is subclass of `UIViewController`. Yet I beleave it's not corresponding to your desirable effect.

If you could use your custom code in `StoryBoard`-based project, try to hide `UINavigationBar` with animated flag equals to `true`:

```cs
// Second parameter - "animated"
NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true, true);
```